# omxplayer for i386?

Tags: omxplayer

I'm developing an application that runs and controls the omxplayer. I very much prefer to develop on my desktop machine, though. So I wonder if it is possible to install omxplayer for a regular desktop Debian (i386)? Are there any builds (I'm on Jessie).

Comment: There's a [3 year old issue](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/8) on the omxplayer Github page which suggests that some of the libraries used are exclusive to the Pi. I don't think you'll be able to compile it for another platform.

Comment: If you write a small application that _behaves_ like omxplayer (except actually doing anything OMX related) you can develop on any machine you want, and then just test on the pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would work.

You still can develop on your i386 desktop and compile/deploy remotely via SSH. That would be the easiest way I can think of. If you really want it, you can setup a cross-compiling environment. But you'd get much overhead in the beginning.

I personally use a set of Makefiles that copy the changes to my Raspberry Pi via `rsync` (only copying deltas) and running `make` on the Pi to compile the code (that changed). It works pretty fast and is convenient.

But for why you should not try to compile `omxplayer` directly on your i386:

`omxplayer` works by utilizing hardware capabilities of the VideoCore IV part of the CPU which has an embedded media encoder and decoder. OMX refers to [OpenMAX](https://www.khronos.org/openmax/) which is an interface to that hardware. I am not aware of any device compatible with OpenMAX except in the mobile/embedded space. But as modern intel/AMD CPUs and also nVidia/AMD GPUs also include hardware media encoder and decoder, they might provide OpenMAX compatible driver. Only then you might have a chance. But still I am not aware of such drivers.

Comment: Openmax runtime is available even in [Debian Wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libomxil-bellagio0)

Comment: I don't doubt that. But do all the devices provide the required driver? Like with OpenGL you need a device and a driver or you end with a software renderer. I'm not aware of a software implementation that fakes a hardware media encoder/decoder.

Comment: I think it's exactly that: a software implementation, much like MESA library for OpenGL. You don't need any device to use it.

Comment: As with OpenGL there need not to be as software implementation. The library works as intended by reporting no compatible devices. Just like you request an OpenGL ES 3 context on the Pi you won't get one and therefore cannot progress. The presence of a library doesn't imply that It can be used without a proper environment.

Comment: I think the issue is that ambiguities in the statement "OpenMAX which is an interface to [the VideoCore IV]" might be taken to imply it is a library specific to that hardware, which it isn't.  However, there are further limitations to `omxplayer` (e.g., since it can use the [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer), it is probably linux specific, which OpenMAX is not).  I doubt there are binaries available for anything but the Pi, and there may be other reasons it cannot be compiled on anything but a Pi.  You can always try though: https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer